# Unable To Display Result Array In Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, time, multiprocessing

Result Array is displayed as empty after trying to append values into it.
I have even declared result as global inside function.
Any suggestions?
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3tyN.png)

Comment: Please don't post your code and errors as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    res= []
    inputData = [a,b,c,d]

    def function(data):
         values = [some_Number_1, some_Number_2]
         return values

    def parallel_run(function, inputData):
         cpu_no = 4
         if len(inputData) < cpu_no:
              cpu_no = len(inputData) 
              p = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_no)
         global resultsAr
         resultsAr = p.map(function, inputData, chunksize=1)
         p.close()
         p.join()
         print ('res = ', res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens since you're misunderstanding the basic point of `multiprocessing`: the child process spawned by `multiprocessing.Process` is *separate* from the parent process, and thus any modifications to data (including global variables) in the child process(es) are not propagated into the parent.

You will need to use `multiprocessing`-specific data types (queues and pipes), or the higher-level APIs provided by e.g. `multiprocessing.Pool`, to get data out of the child process(es).

For your application, the high-level recipe would be

```
def square(v):
    return v * v

def main():
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        squared = p.map(square, arr)
    print(squared)
```

– however you'll likely find that this is massively slower than not using `multiprocessing` due to the overheads involved in such a small task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `multiprocessing.Process` is, as its name says, a separate process. You can imagine it almost as if you're running your script again from the terminal, with very little connection to the mother script.

Therefore, it has its own copy of the `result` array, which it modifies and prints.

The `result` in the "main" process is unmodified.

To convince yourself of this, try to print `id(res)` in both `__main__` and in `square()`. You'll see they are different.

Comment: Since `res` is a global (or in particular, any value created before subprocesses start), `id(res)` can actually be the same in both processes if the multiprocessing `start_method` is `fork`. (On Windows, which OP is using, it won't be.)